# Using Sed to capitalize the first letter of each word

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

Here is the data I want to capitalize:

```
molly w. bolt     334-78-5443
walter q. bugg    984-49-0032
noah p. way       887-12-0921
kerry t. bricks   431-09-1239
ping h. yu        109-32-9845
```

Here is the script I have written so far to capitalize the first letter of name including initial

```
h
s/\(.\).*/\1/
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
G
s/\(.\)\n\(.\)\(.*\)/\1\3/
/ [a-z]/{
h
s/\([A-Z][a-z]* \)\([a-z]\).*/\2/
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
G
s/\(.\)\n\([A-Z][a-z]* \)\(.\)\(.*\)/\2\1\4/
}
/ [a-z]/{
h
s/\([A-Z][a-z]* \)\([a-z]\).*/\2/
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
G
s/\(.\)\n\([A-Z][a-z]* \)\(.\)\(.*\)/\2\1\4/
}
```

It gives me:

```
MOLLY W. BOLT     334-78-544Molly 3. bolt     334-78-5443
WALTER Q. BUGG    984-49-003Walter 2. bugg    984-49-0032
NOAH P. WAY       887-12-092Noah 1. way       887-12-0921
KERRY T. BRICKS   431-09-123Kerry 9. bricks   431-09-1239
PING H. YU        109-32-984Ping 5. yu        109-32-9845
```

I want to only have:

```
Molly W. Bolt     334-78-544
Walter Q. Bugg    984-49-003
Noah P. Way       887-12-092
Kerry T. Bricks   431-09-123
Ping H. Yu        109-32-984
```

What would I change?

Answer (score 6):

How about this (GNU sed):

```
$ sed 's/\b[a-z]/\u&/g' myfile
Molly W. Bolt     334-78-5443
Walter Q. Bugg    984-49-0032
Noah P. Way       887-12-0921
Kerry T. Bricks   431-09-1239
Ping H. Yu        109-32-9845
```

Answer (score 4):

(GNU) Sed what should works with `utf8` too:

```
sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]+/\u&/g'
#or
sed -E 's/\S+/\u&/g'
```

Or perl

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)/\u$1/g'
```

- search for "word-strings" `\w+`
- replace (substitute) `s///` it `$1` with uppercase 1st character `\u`
- everywhere in the line `g`

or the simpler

```
perl -pe 's/\S+/\u$&/g'
```

- any nonspaced string
- capitalize

the

```
perl -CSDA -pe 's/\S+/\u$&/g'
```

will work with `utf8` encoded files too..., e.g. from the

```
павел андреевич чехов 234
γεοργε πατσασογλοθ    123
čajka šumivá          345
```

will print

```
Павел Андреевич Чехов 234
Γεοργε Πατσασογλοθ    123
Čajka Šumivá          345
```

for inline file edit use the next:

```
perl -i.bak -CSDA -pe 's/\S+/\u$&/g' some filenames ....
```

will create the `.bak` (backup) file.

If you have bash 4.2+ and need convert only in the variables, you can use:

```
for name in павел андреевич чехов γεοργε πατσασογλοθ čajka šumivá
do
    echo "${name^}"   #capitalize the $name
done
```

prints

```
Павел
Андреевич
Чехов
Γεοργε
Πατσασογλοθ
Čajka
Šumivá
```

Also, a solution for sed, what doesn;t knows the `\u` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11804643/632407

Comment: where to put -i to make this inline, interesting in console with utf8 didn't show me as should be, with directing output to new file works

Comment: @josifoski edited... (note: changed the `-CS` to `-CSDA`) - every IO and arguments are `utf8`.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple with python also:

```
$ python -c 'with open("myfile") as f:print f.read().title()'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^/ /;s/ [aA]/ A/g;s/ [bB]/ B/g;s/ [cC]/ C/g;s/ [dD]/ D/g;s/ [eE]/ E/g;s/ [fF]/ F/g;s/ [gG]/ G/g;s/ [hH]/ H/g;s/ [iI]/ I/g;s/ [jJ]/ J/g;s/ [kK]/ K/g;s/ [lL]/ L/g;s/ [mM]/ M/g;s/ [nN]/ N/g;s/ [oO]/ O/g;s/ [pP]/ P/g;s/ [qQ]/ Q/g;s/ [rR]/ R/g;s/ [sS]/ S/g;s/ [tT]/ T/g;s/ [uU]/ U/g;s/ [vV]/ V/g;s/ [wW]/ W/g;s/ [xX]/ X/g;s/ [yY]/ Y/g;s/ [zZ]/ Z/g;s/^.//' YourFile
```

Posix (no GNU sed) version
Works on your sample but not if something like `{andrea,georges ...` assuming word are at the start of line OR after a space char here.