# Capitalize first letter of each line

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, terminal

I have a list like below:

```
david
Sam
toNy
3matt
5$!john
```

I wish to capitalize the first occurrence of a letter in each line. So if the line does not begin with a letter then go to the next possible letter and make the into capital. So the above example should output:

```
David
Sam
ToNy
3Matt
5$!John
```

I have tried the following but it does not capitalize the first occurrence of a letter if the line begins with a number or symbol:

```
sed  's/^\(.\)/\U\1/' myfile.txt > convertedfile.txt
```

I have searched this site for answers already and they all give the same problem as the line above

Comment: Related: [How to capitalize first letter of each line in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43705853/2943403), [Using Sed to capitalize the first letter of each word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25962929/2943403), [Uppercasing First Letter of Words Using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538676/2943403), [How can I capitalize the first letter of each word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880597/2943403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\U&/' myfile.txt > convertedfile.txt
```

Here, `s/[[:alpha:]]/\U&/` finds the first letter (with `[[:alpha:]]`) and it is capitalized with `\U` operator (`&` stands for the whole match, the matched letter). As there is no `/g` flag, only the first occurrence (per line) is affected.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/LJCnI6):

```sh
s='david
Sam
toNy
3matt
5$!john'
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\U&/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
David
Sam
ToNy
3Matt
5$!John
```