# Weird awk output contains spaces

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

Why do I get those strange spaces?

```
echo "hello world" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {$1=toupper($1); printf "%s\n", $0}'
```

I get the same result with the simpler way.

```
echo "hello world" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {$1=toupper($1); print}'
```

Output:

```
H e l l o   w o r l d
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but slightly related: [sed/awk capitalize strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11803395/8344060)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the field separator to the empty string has special significance: it reads revery single character into a separate field. Since the output field separator, `OFS`, is unchanged (a blank), your assignment reshuffles the complete record and inserts `OFS` between every single field.

The first field/character is uppercased.

Your first and second method are equivalent because `print` defaults to `print $0`, and `printf "%s\n", $0` is equivalent to `print $0`.

Answer (score 0):

`FS=""` means to treat each character as a separate field. `$0` contains all the fields separated by `OFS`, the output field separator. `OFS` defaults to a single space, so each field is separated by a space.

If you want it to output the result without the extra space, assign to `OFS`

```
echo "hello world" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""; OFS=""} {$1=toupper($1); printf "%s\n", $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason of extra spaces is you didn't set `OFS`.

here is another solution

```
$ echo "hello world" | awk '{sub(/^./,toupper(substr($1,1,1)))}1' 

Hello world
```

or extending your solution

```
$ echo "hello world" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {sub($1,toupper($1))}1'

Hello world
```

not rewriting `$0` will preserve the original format.