# Capitalize entire line and remove strings of a certain length

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

So far I have:

```
cat FileName | tr -s '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

but I cannot figure out how to remove a string, in my case between 4 and 8 characters long. I think I need to use `sed` but I only see ways of removing particular strings, or the beginning or the end of a string - not strings between X and Y length.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please add sample input and the expected output.

Comment: `sed -r 's/[^\s]{4,8}//g'`

Answer (score 1):

You indeed can use `sed`:

```sh
$ cat test.txt 
aaa
bbbb
ccccc
dd
$ sed '/^.\{4\}$/d' test.txt 
aaa
ccccc
dd
```

`^` means the start of string, `$` means the end of the string. `.\{4\}` means a character (`.`) repeated four times (`\{4\}`). The `d` at the end deletes lines if the regexp is matched.

Use `sed -i '/^.\{4\}$/d' test.txt` to apply the changes to file instead of echoing it to stdout.

For a range from 4 to 8 characters, use:

```sh
$ sed '/^.\{4,8\}$/d' test.txt 
aaa
dd
```

To capitalize it:

```sh
 $ sed '/^.\{4,8\}$/d; s/./\u&/g' test.txt 
AAA
DD
```

Resources:
[1] My brain
[2] [Capitalize strings in sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803395/capitalize-strings-in-sed-or-awk)