# How to conditionally replace words with sed?

Tags: sed

My file is in the form:

```
EMPLOYEE
  FIRST NAME: JOHN
  LAST NAME: DOE
  POSITION: ACCOUNT MANAGER
  
EMPLOYEE
  FIRST NAME: BIG
  LAST NAME: BOSS
  POSITION: CEO
```

Well, it's a bit more complex than that, but it is enough to have a solution for it.

I try to fix the casing to title case while keeping the alignment and fields names unchanged:

```
EMPLOYEE
  FIRST NAME: John
  LAST NAME: Doe
  POSITION: Account Manager
  
EMPLOYEE
  FIRST NAME: Big
  LAST NAME: Boss
  POSITION: CEO
```

I have used this so far:

`sed -E '/^\s{0,}(FIRST NAME|LAST NAME|POSITION)/ { s/((^\s{0,})(FIRST NAME|LAST NAME|POSITION))/\1/; T; s/(\b[A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]*)\b/\U\1\L\2/g; }' employees.list`

But it seems not to avoid changing the casing of the field names (FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, POSITION), so these become:

```
EMPLOYEE
  First Name: John
  Last Name: Doe
  Position: Account Manager
  
EMPLOYEE
  First Name: Big
  Last Name: Boss
  Position: Ceo
```

(did not yet go to handle content like `CEO`).

Is this achievable with `sed`? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{0,}`?? Just `*`.

What is really hard is that you want to apply the "first uppercase rest lowercase" regex on *part* of the string. What I usually do, is put part of the input into `h`old space separated by newline, then remove it. Then I can work on the interesting part, finally `g`rab the hold space and res-huffle the output.

```
sed -E '
    /: CEO/{p;d}
    /^(\s*(FIRST NAME|LAST NAME|POSITION):\s*)/{
        # empty s// reuses last regex
        # add a newline betweej <this>: <and this>
        s//\1\n/
        # hold current line with the newline
        h
        # Remove the first part.
        # `\s*` in regex above super nicely "catches" newline added above.
        s///
        # capitalize
        s/\b([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]*)\b/\U\1\L\2/g
        # join with a newline and hold space
        G
        # use the capitalized part with the <prefix:> part.
        s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*).*/\2\1/
    }
'
```

Outputs:

```
EMPLOYEE
  FIRST NAME: John
  LAST NAME: Doe
  POSITION: Account Manager
  
EMPLOYEE
  FIRST NAME: Big
  LAST NAME: Boss
  POSITION: CEO
```

Overall, consider a real programming languages, more like `awk` or `python` etc.

---

Actually, you can capitalize all words and then just re-uppercase the first part, but you would have to how to exclude the `EMPLOYEE` line. So you can just do this:

```
sed -E '
    /: CEO/{p;d}
    /^(\s*(FIRST NAME|LAST NAME|POSITION):\s*)(.*)/{
        s/\b([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]*)\b/\U\1\L\2/g
        s/^(\s*(FIRST NAME|LAST NAME|POSITION):\s*)(.*)/\U\1\E\3/i
    }
'
```

Comment: An `awk`solution is interesting too :).

Comment: Capitalizing strings in Awk is kind of painful. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803595

Comment: If there is a case where `CEO` is `ceo`, how can I add this case to set it uppercase entirely?

Comment: `s/: ceo/\U&/` ?

Comment: Perhaps also note that this uses several non-portable `sed` features; it works fine on many Linuxes, but not e.g. on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/:/{h;s/\S+/\L\u&/g;H;g;s/:.*:/:/}' file
```

If a line contains a `:` then:

Make a copy of the current line.

For each word, lowercase and then uppercase the first character of the word.

Append the current line to the copy.

Replace the current line with the appended copy.

Replace everything between the two `:`'s with `:`.